# Is there a simple way to generate a REST API from a model object in Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, auto-generate

I am looking for some framework or library in Java that allows me to generate a REST API directly from a model object, and at the same time allowing me to map this to a DynamoDB table.

Preferably I would be able to just annotate a model object, a simple example being

```
@Model
public class Book

@Gettable
private String author

@Get
public void getAuthor() {
return this.author;
}
```

and if possible, combine this in some fancy way with the DynamoDBMapper annotations like so

```
@Model
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Book")
public class Book

@Gettable
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Author")
private String author

@Get
public void getAuthor() {
return this.author;
}
```

Comment: Spring is a Java web development framework, and it includes what you're looking for: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: For a person who regularly reviews posts here ... you could know that the "close question" section has this one close reason: **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more** ;-) ... on the other hand, I think that happened to all of us at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It is a quite strange requrements, you have only one object Book with only one Author? For example, in Spring it just:

```
@Entity
public class Book
   private String author;
   ...
}

@RestController
public class BookController
   @GetMapping("/books")
   public List<Book> getBooks() {
      ...
   }
}
```